# Connect cardano-wallet to pre-production testnet

Tags: wallet, docker

We use the prescribed docker compose from iohk. Here is the cardano-wallet excerpt:

```
cardano-wallet:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-wallet:2022.8.16
    container_name: cardano_wallet
    volumes:
      - wallet-testnet-db:/wallet-db
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    ports:
      - 8091:8090
    entrypoint: []
    command: bash -c "
        ([[ $$NETWORK == \"mainnet\" ]] && $$CMD --mainnet) ||
        ($$CMD --testnet /config/$$NETWORK/genesis-byron.json)
      "
    environment:
      CMD: "cardano-wallet serve --node-socket /ipc/node.socket --database /wallet-db --listen-address 0.0.0.0"
      NETWORK: "testnet"
    restart: on-failure
```

Now that we are connecting our node to `pre-production`, we are getting the following error:

```
cardano_wallet    | cardano-wallet: ExceptionInLinkedThread (ThreadId 17) (HandshakeError (Refused NodeToClientV_13 "version data mismatch: NodeToClientVersionData {networkMagic = NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 1}} /= NodeToClientVersionData {networkMagic = NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 1097911063}}"))
```

This makes sense to me. It looks like the wallet is trying to connect to the old testnet using the old network magic `1097911063`. The problem is that it isn't clear how to get it to connect to preprod instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that iohk updated the `2022.8.16` image tag with new configurations but without creating a new tag. If someone gets the latest version of that image then using `NETWORK=preprod` should work.